# How to enable the colorbutton in the TYPO3 CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor, typo3, typo3-8.x, rte, typo3-extensions

I'm trying to enable the [colorbutton](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/colorbutton) plugin to use the TextColor feature in the TYPO3 CKEditor but it won't work.

I've already tried to include all needed external plugins which are required by the colorbutton plugin. I've downloaded the plugins for the Version 4.7 directly from the CKEditor website ([button](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/button), [panelbutton](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/panelbutton), [panel](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/panel), [floatpanel](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/floatpanel)). But everytime when I include panelbutton or colorbutton the Editor in the TYPO3 Backend doesn't work anymore.

Code where the plugins are getting included:
[image: Code where the plugins gets included]

Editor broke after including panelbutton or colorbutton plugins:
[image: Editor broke after including panelbutton or colorbutton]
My goal is to have this button in the toolbar:
[image: goal]

Comment: Maybe the .js cannot be loaded because /Resources/Private has a .htaccess Deny from all in it?

Comment: @flightwusel you're right! After I've changed that to the /Resources/Public directory the files could be loaded correctly and the editor didn't crashed anymore. The button still doesn't load but I think this is because of an error in the config. I will post update and solution soon...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following configuration should work:

```
editor:
    config:
        toolbarGroups:
            - { name: colors }

        extraPlugins:
            - colorbutton

        #configuration example:
        colorButton_colors: "F49800,B9B9B9,75A75A"
```

Answer (score 3):

For people who are still struggling by adding the colorbutton Plugin to the TYPO3 CKEditor here is my final solution:

The custom.yaml file is created with this [documentation](https://www.thomaskieslich.de/blog/127-typo3-8x-ckeditor-konfigurieren/), see the downloadable [yaml file](https://www.thomaskieslich.de/fileadmin/media/blog/2016/201602-ckeditor/Custom1.yaml) at the end of the page.
All CKEditor plugins can be downloaded directly from the offical [addons plugin page](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addons/plugins/all). Don't forget to include possible dependencies. I've downloaded the plugins for the version 4.7 and it's working fine. Make sure you place the plugins inside the Public and not the Private directory, this was my mistake.

**custom.yaml:**

```
[...]
editor:
  externalPlugins:
    button: { resource: "EXT:yourSitePackage/Resources/Public/ckeditor/plugins/button/plugin.js" }
    panelbutton: { resource: "EXT:yourSitePackage/Resources/Public/ckeditor/plugins/panelbutton/plugin.js" }
    panel: { resource: "EXT:yourSitePackage/Resources/Public/ckeditor/plugins/panel/plugin.js" }
    floatpanel: { resource: "EXT:yourSitePackage/Resources/Public/ckeditor/plugins/floatpanel/plugin.js" }
    colorbutton: { resource: "EXT:yourSitePackage/Resources/Public/ckeditor/plugins/colorbutton/plugin.js" }

  config:
    extraPlugins:
      - button
      - panelbutton
      - panel
      - floatpanel
      - colorbutton

    toolbar:
      - { name: 'colors', items: [ 'TextColor', 'BGColor' ] }
    [...]

    colorButton_enableAutomatic: false
    colorButton_enableMore: false
    colorButton_colors: 000000,167951,93C0BD,F48E00
  [...]
```

**Final Result:**
[image: Result of TYPO3 CKEditor with colorbutton plugin]

Comment: I think that you also need to add an entry in the toolbarGroups with   
`toolbarGroups:  `
 `- { name: colors }`

Comment: and the `colorButton_colors` options etc, should be inside the config section and not on the same level as the config?

Comment: @StefanosKarasavvidis doesn't matter if you use toolbarGroups OR just toolbar. See the docs: https://ckeditor.com/latest/samples/old/toolbar/toolbar.html

Comment: @StefanosKarasavvidis Thanks I‘ve fixed the indent.

Comment: you are correct. It didn't work for me because I had put toolbar outside of config.  For people basing the configuration on the TYPO3 provided example: as the TYPO3 configuration comes with toolbargroups instead of toolbars, it will be easier try out this solution by adding `- { name: colors }` to the toolbarGroups

Comment: @JanFässler thank you for doc url...i was having problem in configuration of bgcolor and text color and correct config i found into url that you shared 
 { name: 'colors', items: [ 'TextColor', 'BGColor' ] }